# In Rails, how to display date like NOV 22, '09?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, how to display date like NOV 22, '09?

And time like:  5:10 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date.today.strftime "%b %d, '%y"
Time.now.strftime "%I:%M%p"
```

Comment: Date.today ... seems to be failing, NameError?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the section 3.2, "Adding Date and Time Formats", in th [Internationalization Rails Guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) You'll declare the format in a locales file using (I believe):

```
# config/locales/custom.yml
custom:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "%b %d, '%y"
```

and call it in your view with:

```
<p><%= l Time.now, :format => :short %></p>
```